# Конвертация QString в double

Tags: qt, строки

При конвертации QString в double происходит конвертация в int.

```
QString str= QString("173214.25");
qDebug()<<str.toDouble();
```

> Вывод:"173214"

Почему?

Comment: Почему что? Что вы ожидали увидеть?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, 173214.25, очевидно

Comment: Все просто: при конверсии происходит округление. [Ответ на англ. SO в одно предложение](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35813756/how-to-print-double-with-all-decimals-in-qt).

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, и как же мне тогда получить исходное число?

Comment: Попробуйте как в англ. версии `qDebug() << QString::number(str.toDouble(), 'g', 17);` или `qDebug() << qSetRealNumberPrecision( 10 ) << "x = " << str.toDouble();`.

Comment: Ну, как, сработало?

Answer (score 2):

По умолчанию, `qDebug()` округляет переменные типа double до первого целого числа. Чтобы этого избежать, задайте точность преобразования переменных типа *double* в строку. Используйте

```
qDebug() << QString::number(str.toDouble(), 'g', 17);
```

или

```
qDebug() << qSetRealNumberPrecision( 10 ) << "x = " << str.toDouble();
```